# Countin words from one file, in another Python

Tags: python

I am trying to count the amount of times words from a file shows up in a another file. I was directed to the link below, which was of assistance but still isn't doing the desired duty. Can someone help me?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144074/program-to-count-vowels

```
def count_happyW(file):
    hap_count = 0
    for Hwords in file.readlines():
        line = file.readline()
        while line != "":
            for item in Hwords:
                if item in file:
                    count_happyW[item] += 1
                    return hap_count
```

I also tried

```
line = file.readline()
total = 1 * [len(h_words) for line in file.readline()]
for token in file.readlines():   
    while line != "":     
        line = file.readline()     
        for item in h_words:         
            if item in file:              
                total = [1] * len(item)
```

Comment: Could you add input and expected output? As it currently stands the question is bit unclear.

Comment: Are you trying to count words in the corresponding file? Or are you trying to count how many times a specific word appears?

Comment: @niemmi sorry about that! I can add the expected input, for the first try, it doesn't print anything out. But for my other try, it will print out how many lines are in the file that Im checking contains the words, but not the amount of words in each line of the file, but the total number of keywords that I originally have in the file

Comment: @siavashk I have a list of about 30 words, and I'm trying to to see how many times each of those words appear in the corresponding file

Answer (score 0):

yourwords.txt contains words you are searching for space separated, my contents:

> apple orange bananna

yourfile.txt is your file that you search in:

> apple orange bananna
>
> an apple on the orange tree

```
wordcount = {}
with open('yourwords.txt', 'r') as f1, open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as f2:
    words = f1.read().split()
    wordcount = { i:0 for i in words}
    for line in f2:
        line_split = line.split()
        for word in line_split:
          if word in wordcount: 
            wordcount[word] += 1

print(wordcount)
```

Output:

> {'bananna': 1, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 2}

Comment: Ok I am trying this out!

Comment: Well, this works a bit better than what I had. but instead prints that all the keywords I'm looking for = 0.... I have about 100 lines of file that I'm checking contain the keywords, and some of them do but all of them say 0

Comment: Like the output, with your example, instead of it being {'bananna': 1, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 2}, its 0 for both even though the file.txt is apple orange bananna

an apple on the orange tree

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I am going to assume you have two files. The first file will contain the words you want to search for separated by a new line. The second file will contain some text.

File 1: (words.txt)

```
dog
cat
went
```

File 2: (story.txt)

```
Today my cat and dog ran out of my backyard.
This is not the first time my dog has ran away. 
Last time he went to the dog park and then went to my neighbors house.
```

First you would want to create a dictionary containing each of the key words in the `words.txt` file. You would make the value of this the amount of times it has been seen in the second file.

```
wordDB = { 'dog': 0, 'cat': 0, 'went' : 0}
```

To do this dynamically you would first create an empty dictionary and then loop of the lines in the `words.txt` file.

```
wordDB = {}
wordFile = open('words.txt','r')
for line in wordFile.readlines():
    word = line.replace('\n','') #This replaces the new line character
    if not(word in wordDB.keys()): #Checks that the word doesn't already exist.
        wordDB[word] = 0 # Adds the word to the DB.
wordFile.close()
```

Now we need to open the second file and loop over each line in that file. For each line in that file we will check each key in the wordDB and if it exists increment its count respectively.

```
storyFile = open('story.txt','r')
checkWordList = wordDB.keys()
for line in storyFile.readlines():
    wordList = line.replace('\n','').split(' ')
    for eachWord in checkWordList:
        if eachWord in wordList:
            wordDB[eachWord] = (wordDB[eachWord] + wordList.count(eachWord) )

storyFile.close()
```

Now you just need to loop over the checkWordList one more time and print out the value from the wordDB.

```
for eachWord in checkWordList:
    print "%s : %s" % (eachWord, wordDB[eachWord])
```

You would get the output:

```
went: 2
dog: 3
cat: 1
```

Comment: I get this: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'keys'                                    However, I have multiple lines in the "story.txt" file and for each like, I have to check if the keywords are in it. and if it does it adds it to a total. so like if one of the lines has 4 keywords, then the total for that line is.. 4. and if another line has 5 then the total for that line is 5.

Comment: Ive been working on this for two weeks now but nothing is working and its really stressing

Comment: ?? Hello, can you please assist?